# Moving entries from one select to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox and two list boxes.

The first list box is populated from a database based on what is typed in the textbox. Items should move from one list box to the other depending on which button is pressed.

However at the moment once it does this, then both lists seem to get cleared.

Can anyone see why this is the case.

The following is the JavaScript

```
$('#txtMRN').keyup(function () {
    var s = $('#txtMRN').val();
    var l = s.length;
    var lst = document.getElementById('lstMRN');


    if (l > 4)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:52238/PatientsGetLike.ashx?MRN=" + s,
            success: function (result) {
                lst.innerHTML = '';
                $.each(result, function (i, v) {
                    var newOption = document.createElement('option');

                    newOption.text = v.nhs_patientid + ' - ' + v.nhs_surname + ', ' + v.nhs_firstname;
                    newOption.setAttribute('value', v.nhs_patientid);
                    newOption.className = 'mdl-list__item';

                    lst.add(newOption);

                });

                componentHandler.upgradeDom(lst);

            }
        });
    }
});

$('#btnSelect').click(function () {
    var el1 = document.getElementById('lstMRN');
    var el2 = document.getElementById('lstMRNSelected');

    $('#lstMRN :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
        var opt         = document.createElement('option');

        opt.value       = selected.value;
        opt.text        = selected.text;
        opt.className   = 'mdl-list__item';

        el2.add(opt);
        // selected.remove();
    });

});
```

and the HTML for the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>EPR Document Sweep </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.teal-amber.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="Styles/Styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <div class="mdl-layout__title">
                    EPR Document Sweep
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right" id="searchBox">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="srchText">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="srchText" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
                <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">
                        <i class="material-icons">link</i>
                        Intranet
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Document Sweep</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Add MRNs</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Log</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <main class="mdl-layout__content">
            <form action="#">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="txtMRN">
                    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="txtMRN">MRN</label>
                </div>  
                <div style="width:100%;" >
                    <div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
                        <select size="4" name="lstMRN" id="lstMRN" class="mdl-list listBox"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:text-top;">
                        <button id="btnSelect" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored selectButtons">
                            &gt;                        
                        </button>

                        <button id="btnDeselect" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored selectButtons">
                            &lt;
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">
                        <select size="4" name="lstMRNSelected" id="lstMRNSelected" class="mdl-list listBox"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Default.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to remove the space `#lstMRN :selected`

Comment: Tried that - remove the space and the loop does not execute at all.

Comment: I forgot one more thing: `#lstMRN option:selected`.. You search for the `option`s tag not the select.

Comment: Solved it - tried option:selected, however the problem was it was doing a submit - that effectively cleared both lists. Added the following code: $("selectForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

That effectively solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form was being submitted - effectively clearing the two lists. . Change the form tag to the following;

```
<form action="#" id="selectForm">
```

Add the following code to the script file

```
$("#selectForm").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```